# nuxt 3 useFetch() returns the error fetch failed()

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, runtime-error, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have set up the nuxt 3 from the nuxt 3 official documents and used the only useFetch() composable to fetch data in app.vue file but it returns the error `Error: fetch failed()` when we reload the page.

[image: Please check the error here]

Please check my below code of app.vue file

```html
<template>
{{data}}
</template>

<script setup>
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',
  {
    method: "get",
  });

  console.log(data.value);
  if (error.value) {
    console.log(error.value);
  }
</script>
```

I have tried useFetch and useLazyFetch composable to fetch the data but both returns the same error when we reload the page. I think there is some issue with client side or server side but don't know much about this. Also useFetch() returns result correctly when we visit that page again but it occurring error on initial api call or we hard reload the page.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my side, even after a hard refresh. Are you using nuxt `v3.0.0`? Also, which package manager are you using? Do you have a public GitHub repo? Are you using v18 or v16?

Comment: @kissu Yes I am using nuxt version `v3.0.0`, 
Node Version: `v19.3.0`
Package manager: `npm`
Do you have a public GitHub repo: `No`

Please let me know if you need with any other things.

Comment: Don't use an unstable version of Node. Use v18 or v16 rather (even versions).

Comment: @kissu I have tried with node version `18.12.1, 18.0.0, 16.0.0,` still it returns the same error. I just switch one by one mentioned version->delete package.loc.json file -> delete node module->npm install->npm run dev

Still returns the same error. Please help me with this. Also, I think there is some SSR and client side rendering issue?

Comment: Try to also delete the `.nuxt` directory, it's a cache. Remove `method: get` also, it's not needed. Try with `yarn` and maybe Firefox just to see if you have some other error (more verbose). I know that NPM can have some issues getting all the dependencies sometimes. How have you created the project? With `npx`? Your code snippet works well on my side. Also, what is your OS ?

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your answering on this. My OS is `ubuntu` and I have create the project with the command `npx nuxi init <project-name>` from [link]https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation this documentation Meanwhile I am trying to removing the .nuxt folder with `yarn` I will get back soon if its work or not.

Comment: @kissu I just created a fresh nuxt3 setup and used `yarn` with node version `18.12.1` but still, it returns the same error `Error: fetch failed ()`. Even it returns some experimental error `ERROR  (node:60811) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time` when we run `yarn install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is we need to add `ssr: false` in `nuxt.config.js`. Maybe SSR is true by default if we need to use server-side rendering but if we want the single file application we need to keep `ssr: false`. The above error is fixed with this.

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: false,
})
```

Comment: This is more a workaround than a fix. Without SSR, you don't really need `useFetch`, since the fetch just happens on the client, anyway.

Comment: @rudolfbyker Can you please tell me if this above is the valid fix or not?

Comment: As I said, this is a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: @rudolfbyker what about Axios if we could use it with nuxt 3 to overcome this if make sens

Answer (score 4):

Real subject here is why fetch or axios.get would fail in SSR mode and what configuration allows us to keep SSR and still get data.
Still looking into that on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an 'await' prior to your 'useFetch' call as shown in [the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch).

@kishan for reference, here is a way to refactor your example:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// api call (async implied in this context)
// this call is a GET by default
const { data, error } = await useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains')

// log response (data will be a ref)
if (error.value) console.log('ERROR from useFetch: ', error.value)
if (data.value) console.log('data returned from useFetch: ', data)
</script>
```

Comment: @kissu Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried with your provided code but still returning the same error `ERROR from useFetch:  Error: fetch failed ()`. I have also tried `server: false` but still it not working.

Comment: I think there is one setting on `nuxt.config.ts` file `ssr: false` I just did it and it is working fine. Can you please explain whether this is the right way or not and when we need to keep this `ssr: false`? If you can explain with a real scenario or example that would be great!..! Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nodejs 18+? If so, there's a [bug](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/issues/156) related to the ofetch library that prevents it from working on node 18+.
Nuxt works in SSR mode by default, so when you do server-side requests (useFetch composable), it is processed in the node server. That's why turning off SSR fixes your problem (as the request happens in the browser).
However, we can't call that a proper solution cause you don't need those composables once you are in the browoser as rudolfbyker said.
So downgrading to node 16 fixes your issue (till the bug gets resolved upstream)

Comment: I am using `Node v 19` I have tried with node 16 but it was no working hence I have done `ssr: false` Is this an appropriate fix?

Comment: As I said, disabling SSR so you don't face the fetch bug is like riding a bike since a motorcycle runs out of gas. It beats the purpose. But if doing client-side rendering fits your needs, then why not :D

Comment: Yes I am working on single page application so there no need of server side rendering

Answer (score 0):

I believe this modification could work

```
<template>
{{data}}
</template>

<script setup>
await nextTick(()=>{
   const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',
      {
        method: "get",
      });

  console.log(data.value);
  if (error.value) {
    console.log(error.value);
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Node to 20.9 solved this problem for me.

Comment: I updated to Node v20.10.0, However I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @kissu said you need to add an 'await' prior to your 'useFetch' call as shown in the docs. In this case Nuxt throws error if it has a request to render data which isn't provided. You can use pending so Nuxt won't have to render and in further throw an error

```
<template>
{{pending ? 'loading' : data}}
</template>

<script setup>
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',
  {
    method: "get",
  });

  if (error.value) console.log('ERROR from useFetch: ', error.value)
  if (data.value) console.log('data returned from useFetch: ', data.value)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem which others say. I needed to DELETE `await` from before `useFetch` and `storeToRefs` inside the < script setup>...< /script>