# Nuxt 3 data not loading on page change

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am creating a project in Nuxt 3 (latest version). The problem I have now is that when I switch from routes (from url https://example.com/a to url https://example.com/b) the data is not loaded. When I refresh the page the data is loaded and displayed.

Have been trying to figure out why but I am unable to find an answer and I was hoping someone here would know what the problem might be.

Below is an example of a page:

```
<script setup>
import {useFetch} from "nuxt/app";

defineI18nRoute({
  paths: {
    nl: '/category/[category]',
    de: '/category/[category]',
    pl: '/category/[category]',
  }
})

const localePath = useLocalePath()
const route = useRoute()

let { data } = await useFetch(`https://example.com/api/nl/category/${route.params.category}`)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="w-full mx-auto max-w-4xl px-4">
    <ul class="list-disc pl-3 space-y-1 text-sm mb-12" v-if="data">
      <li v-for="(part, partIndex) in JSON.parse(data).articles" :key="partIndex" class="hover:text-green-700">
        <NuxtLink :to="localePath(`/${part.slug}`)" :title="part.title">
          {{ part.title }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

What I expect is that the data loads and displays each individual page. What happens currently is that the page (and url) do load, but no content is displayed until I press F5 to refresh the page.

Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does your API coming from the server folder or an external?

Comment: The API is an external folder!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are using the exact same template file, you can manually trigger a refresh for `useFetch` whenever the route changes.

```
let { data, refresh } = await useFetch(`https://example.com/api/nl/category/${route.params.category}`)

watch(route, value => {
  refresh()
})
```

See https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#usefetch

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the case. What happens is when I click on a link (NuxtRoute) I go to the new page, the URL changes accordingly, but the data is not displayed until I hit the F5 button.

I tried adding the watcher with the refresh option but that didn't do anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `useFetch` etc in nuxt yet myself, only read the docs so far but here is some things to try (best guesses):

## 1. Is it reactive?

If `data` is natively a reactive property, using destructs (`let { data } = await...`) causes loss of reactivity.

Try `const request = await` and `JSON.parse(request.data)`

If `data` is not reactive in general then this wont work, the component wont know to re-render after a new request is made because the page does not change when a URI slug changes when looking at the same page component.

## 2. Try a computed method

`const articles = computed(() => JSON.parse(data).articles)`

`<li v-for="(part, partIndex) in articles">`

> I forget if its `articles` or `articles.value` in a for loop.

## 3. Use a reactive state and wrapper function

```js
const articles = reactive([])

const fetchArticles = async () => {
  const { data, refresh } = await useFetch(`https://example.com/api/nl/category/${route.params.category}`)

  articles = JSON.parse(data).articles
}

await fetchArticles()
```

> You may still need to combine this with the other answer about using `watch` to observe for URI changes and trigger `refresh`, its usually a typical requirement to do so unless nuxt3 is do doing some magic stuff under the hood already, but I doubt it?

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work... almost as if it is a routing problem and not something with the data. I see the "watcher" console.log an ouput, yet no content until I press refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884488/nuxt-3-usefetch-returns-the-error-fetch-failed)
You need to keep `ssr: false` it's true by default

[nuxt 3 useFetch() returns the error fetch failed()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884488/nuxt-3-usefetch-returns-the-error-fetch-failed)

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: false,
})
```