# useFetch() response value not accessible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt's `useFetch` method to fetch data from the API, and I've come across the issue of not being able to access response data immediately:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
    useFetch('/listings')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.value)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```

The `console.log` is logging `null`, but if I add `setTimeout` to the `.then` block, then it is working, and is returning an `array of objects`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(response.data.value)
}, 1000)
```

Logging only `response.data` (without `.value`) is returning a `proxy object` that has `_value`, and I can access the value from the console, but trying to access it directly with `response.data.value` isn't working. Also, by checking the browsers' network tab, and backend logs, I can see that the API is returning an array of objects.

I also tried to use `useFetch` method by declaring the data variable and using `async/await`, but had the same result.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: A quick look at [the documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#return-values) shows that there's a `pending` property on `response` that can be `true` to indicate *"...whether the data is still being fetched."* So apparently, just because the promise is fulfilled, that doesn't mean the fetch is complete. (I don't use Nuxt, just looked at the docs.)

Comment: Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] featuring the described issue. Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why the data is not displaying it is because your route is on ssr by [default](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction#server-side-rendering).

If you want to display the data using your codes above without using the timeout function, consider disabling the SSR in your route. You can do that by using the `routeRules` in your nuxt config. More information on this [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering) about rendering

I created an example for you with the ssr disabled on this specific route only.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-oq7mks?file=pages/not-ssr-page.vue

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/your-path/': { ssr: false }
    }
})
```

If you don't want to disable the SSR in your route, then you should consider using the `interceptors`. Learn more about the interceptors in the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) bottom part.

Using the interceptors, you will see the response data in the console.

Example usage

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  const { data } = await useFetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'GET',
    onResponse(context) {
      console.log('Interceptor', context.response._data);
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

I created an example for it as well
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-oq7mks?file=pages/index.vue

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to stop the ssr as by default nuxt comes with ssr you can disable ssr by doing `ssr: false` on `nuxt.config.ts` file
Please check this [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884488/nuxt-3-usefetch-returns-the-error-fetch-failed) I had the same issue and fixed using ssr: false